# command line optional arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, biopython, sys

so i am still coding and not even sure if this all works yet, but it's hard to test it when i can't even get it to run.  this is my first time trying to have multiple optional inputs and every time i run it i get the error:

"Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `sequence_filename'"

the command line input is a filename (require) and then the optional output file that the function will run and then an optional variable of either prot (if it's a protein, the defualt) or na if it's a nucleic acid

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sequence_filename = sys.argv[1]
    output_filename = ''
    if sys.argv > 3:
        output_filename = sys.argv[2]
        if sys.argv[3] == 'na':
            input = 'na'
        else:
            input = 'prot'
    elif sys.argv > 2:
        output_filename = sys.argv[2]

    main( sequence_filename, output_filename, input )
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you passing the full path of your file?

Comment: no.  it is just the filename (something.fa) that is in the same folder that i am working in.  is that what you meant?

Comment: Instead of `if sys.argv > 3:` it should be `if len(sys.argv) > 3:`

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing complicated command-line interface, you should use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html), which will parse and make the interface automatically based on the arguments you specify.

If you're running python 2.6 or older, you can use [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), the older module that was replaced by `argparse`.

Comment: Even if you're not doing a "serious command-line interface", argparse is a good idea - it's easier and less bug-prone.

Comment: Still, I wouldn't use it if I only need a script to process a file that I specify on argv[1], for example. But as soon as you get flags and optional args, that's of course a need.

Comment: alas i am running an older version of python and argparse does not seem to exist.  when i import it i am told as much.